# Extract data from a MongoDB database using the Mongo Java Driver

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb

I'm trying to write a program in Java that will connect to a MongoDB database. I already have the server, port, name, userDB, and username/password of the MongoDB database I'm trying to access.

I wasn't really sure where to start, so after looking around for a bit, I found a Java driver for MongoDB available on GitHub:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver. I downloaded the source code and imported it as a project on Eclipse. The source code for the driver has literally hundreds if not thousands of files. I tried running it as is, and couldn't get the project to compile.

I have no clue where to go from here. There isn't a lot of in-depth instructional material out there for this, and if I took the time to thoroughly inspect all the files in the driver, that could take decades.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial, but you are required to use Spring framework though, http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the .JAR file from here: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/3.0.0/

You need mongodb-driver-3.0.0.jar from this list.

Once you have that add it as a library dependency in your Eclipse project and you'll be all set.

Comment: Two answers by different people with the same username ! That's a first for me :)

Comment: @Sid I almost left the page thinking I have already answered the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track here. What you need to do instead of downloading the source code is to download the JAR files or alternatively use Maven which is a dependency management tool.

This is what you will need to [install](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/installation-guide/) the mongodb driver.
After you have successfully added the dependencies to your project. Use [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/) quick start guide which will step you through the basics.

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/) is an example of working with maven.

Don't get disheartened by small trials..there's always decades of documentation to read ;)